# CSS for textarea should resize vertical

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, design

I've noticed that on Firefox and Chrome that the textareas are resizable vertically as well as horizontally; the `resize` rule not having been set.  I occasionally break the layout a bit when I resize the textarea using the browser's built-in handle instead of the drag bar.

```
resize: vertical;
```

or

```
resize: none;
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: [We did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/prevent-the-post-text-area-from-being-obscured-by-the-sidebar-when-resized). ;P Also, I have no as Userstyle which does this globally, comes in handy on all sites. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was completed. I need an answer to mark as accepted, this is simply a placeholder.