# Prevent the post text area from being obscured by the sidebar when resized

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor

When I try to resize the input box, I get overlap by the Similar Questions box. Obviously this isn't very useful.

Maybe a way to disable it automagically when I resize or finding a new geometry for it?
[image: Overlap]

Comment: one of Chrome's great features is the resizing of textareas...sorry! I didn't -1 you by the way...your question may well prove useful to others wondering the same

Comment: Probably the best solution for the SE developers is to apply `resize:none;` styling to the `<textarea>`.  That would certainly solve your problem :-)

Comment: @Andy That'd unfortunately break a useful browser feature for those of us who resize text boxes without getting in trouble.

Comment: @Anna: it just seems like it would be appropriate, given the fixed-width nature of the sites.

Answer (score 4):

+1.  I don't think there is a reason why the edit box can have an opaque background and a higher (if not the highest) z-index.

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>Also, people who don't format their code so that the horizontal scrollbar isn't needed should be punched in the face.</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: +1 POW! Right in the kisser.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, this is exclusively a browser 'feature': I'll assume you're using Chrome?

Regardless, this is *not* a bug with any particular bearing on SO, it is a bigger issue than that. I'd perhaps recommend researching into this topic in an area where there is an active community, or support for your specific browser.

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome

Comment: Site's without cross-browser support's are known as Site's with bugs so im sory to Disappoint you Mr.Disappointment

Answer (score 3):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), sort of, but not in the way you wanted. There's a good reason that [the standard defaults resizing to be turned off](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css3-ui-20040511/#resize); unfortunately, some browsers ignore this. Vertical resizing of the editor is okay, but that's already possible via the TextAreaResizer plugin which works in *all* browsers. As far as horizontal resizing goes, I agree with Andy E.'s comments on your question.

For freely resizable text areas to be considered supported, everything else has to take this possibility into consideration. But when we say we want the editor to have a width of 660 pixels, we mean it, since the rest of the page is styled under that assumption.

The fact that both Firefox and Chrome default this to "on" for text areas is wrong and thus broken. So `textarea { resize: none }` is now part of the CSS reset.

Comment: I have to disagree. For me that's an awesome feature, but also for me it's logical that the design gets broken if I resize something with external means. ... Great, that now means I have to look up on how to make the browser completely ignore that setting?

Comment: @Bobby It's not really an "external means"; it's part of the CSS standard. If this was e.g. some browser addon that does this, we could ignore it; it would be just like changing CSS via Firebug, which is obviously not supported by us. But the resizing is part of the standard, and Firefox and Chrome chose the wrong default value. So just like other issues where browsers are broken, we have to make sure that we're somewhat cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was in the CSS3 standard *that* way. I never saw it as part of the page itself, so I never expected it to work with the side, and if stuff got broken I just accepted that. That it is in the standard changes that, of course. Though I'd like to tell you that it is nonsense to disable it completely (because it sucks for me, I was using that *extensively* and didn't care for the broken layout), I can completely understand that point.

Comment: Agreed, for the most part. We probably wouldn't have touched it if there had been no complaints. Anyway, as I said [in that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118740/make-textareas-vertically-resizable/118763#118763), we have no problem with specifically enabling it in spots where it makes sense and doesn't cause issues. We just *default* to off, like the W3C intended.