# Post text-area Resize Issue

Tags: bug, posting, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magically reposition it when changing size of question body input box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/magically-reposition-it-when-changing-size-of-question-body-input-box)

On some Browser's the text-area(`wmd-input`) where Post content is ,it is being resized Horizontally and Vertically .

By re-sizing Horizontally  ,it hides behind Sidebar Content ,so if SO wont disable Horizontal Resize than could just increase Z-Index because some times when i Drop the resize behind Sidebar content i wont be able to resize again and it becomes very hard to read the Content.

PS : Why is there a Resize Bar for Vertical re-size and Text-Area feature for both resize